# zxing with compose for qr scan

Tags: kotlin, zxing, android-jetpack-compose

I want to implemented qr scanner using zxing and compose.
I tried it many times but fail.
How can I implemented it?

This code didn't work for me.

```
@Composable
fun AdminClubMembershipScanScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var scanFlag by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    val compoundBarcodeView = remember {
        CompoundBarcodeView(context).apply {
            val capture = CaptureManager(context as Activity, this)
            capture.initializeFromIntent(context.intent, null)
            this.setStatusText("")
            capture.decode()
            this.decodeContinuous { result ->
                if(scanFlag){
                    return@decodeContinuous
                }
                scanFlag = true
                result.text?.let { barCodeOrQr->
                    //Do something and when you finish this something
                    //put scanFlag = false to scan another item
                    scanFlag = false
                }
                //If you don't put this scanFlag = false, it will never work again.
                //you can put a delay over 2 seconds and then scanFlag = false to prevent multiple scanning 
                
            }
        }
    }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier,
        factory = { compoundBarcodeView },
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Compose interop [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose):

> Note: Constructing the view in the AndroidView viewBlock is the best practice. Do not hold or remember a direct view reference outside AndroidView.

Instead you should create your view inside `factory` - it also will give you the context, so you don't need `LocalContext`.

But main problem why it doesn't work for you, is that you're not starting the camera. You should call `resume()` to do so. So final code can look like this:

```
var scanFlag by remember {
    mutableStateOf(false)
}

AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        CompoundBarcodeView(context).apply {
            val capture = CaptureManager(context as Activity, this)
            capture.initializeFromIntent(context.intent, null)
            this.setStatusText("")
            capture.decode()
            this.decodeContinuous { result ->
                if (scanFlag) {
                    return@decodeContinuous
                }
                println("scanFlag true")
                scanFlag = true
                result.text?.let { barCodeOrQr ->
                    println("$barCodeOrQr")
                    //Do something and when you finish this something
                    //put scanFlag = false to scan another item
                    scanFlag = false
                }
                //If you don't put this scanFlag = false, it will never work again.
                //you can put a delay over 2 seconds and then scanFlag = false to prevent multiple scanning
            }
            this.resume()
        }
    },
    modifier = Modifier
)
```

Comment: @Kyu-HoHwang You're welcome. As this solved your problem please accept this answer using a checkmark under the votes counter =)

Comment: I hope to ask a question. It didn't work at the kindle fire, however, previous code is working at it. It says, "java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service" "E/CameraInstance: Failed to configure camera" "E/WindowManager: App trying to use insecure INPUT_FEATURE_NO_INPUT_CHANNEL flag. Ignoring"

Comment: @Kyu-HoHwang What's the previous code? How is this different from the current one? Does this code works on a regular android device? First of all check that your permissions in the manifest are the same, including that you've followed [zxing documentation](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) instructions. If this didn't help, you should ask an other question, because it didn't seems to be related to this one.